# why the same code was executed in subprocess and main process?

Tags: python-3.x

i wrote the code in test.py

```
from multiprocessing import  Process
from time import sleep, ctime
import multiprocessing

def func(name, sec):
    print('---begin---', name, 'time', ctime())
    sleep(sec)
    print('***end***', name, 'time', ctime())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Process(target=func, args=('first', 11))
    t1.start()
    print("s2",multiprocessing.process.current_process().name)

print("sl",multiprocessing.process.current_process().name)
```

i ran the test.py,and the result was:

```
s2 MainProcess
sl MainProcess
sl Process-1
---begin--- first time Mon Mar  6 16:45:20 2023
***end*** first time Mon Mar  6 16:45:31 2023
```

i don't understand why the s1... executed in the subprocess "Process-1"

Comment: i thought only the code in the function "func" would execute in the subprocess

Answer (score 0):

There is a warning about this in documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-safe-main-import), and also [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers). The way `Process` works is by launching a new Python executable, which then proceeds to `import` the file containing your target function. Since the line `print("sl"...)` is not protected by a conditional (`if __name__ == "__main__"` guard) or a function definition, it is executed during the import.

Let's take multiprocessing out of the picture. Imagine you have two files:

```
# lib.py

def hello(who):
    print(f"Hello, {who}!")

print("Successfully imported lib")

# main.py

import lib
lib.hello("world")
```

When you run `main.py`, the output is

```
Successfully imported lib
Hello, world!
```

This is because `import` executes the module content, if it was not already loaded. It will first execute `def hello` to define the `hello` function, then it will execute `print` to print `Successfully imported lib` (even though we did not explicitly order such printing from the main module). After this, `lib` is made available to the `main` file, so we can call `lib.hello`.

In the same way, when you launch a `Process`, the subprocess Python interpreter must somehow get the definition of your `func`. Since it can't get the definition directly from the parent process, like it could in case of Thread, it does so by executing the `test.py` file, which results in the bare `print` getting executed as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you spawned a subprocess, the behavior is just like what Amadan said.
If you want to get rid of that, you can change your process starting method to fork before creating subprocesses, which will just copy the memory space of parent process and step forward.

```py
from multiprocessing import  Process
from time import sleep, ctime
import multiprocessing

def func(name, sec):
    print('---begin---', name, 'time', ctime())
    sleep(sec)
    print('***end***', name, 'time', ctime())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # added here
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')
    t1 = Process(target=func, args=('first', 11))
    t1.start()
    print("s2",multiprocessing.process.current_process().name)

print("sl",multiprocessing.process.current_process().name)
```

But make sure you know what's going to happen before getting into it.